# If $f$ decreases and $\sum n^{a-1}{f(n)}^a<\infty$ then $\sum 2^n (2^n)^{a-1}{f(2^n)}^a$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a\in(0,1]$ and $f:\mathbb{Z}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ be a decrasing function such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{a-1}{f(n)}^a<\infty.$$ Prove that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n (2^n)^{a-1}{f(2^n)}^a<\infty.\tag{1}$$

I think that if the problem were to prove that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2^n)^{a-1}{f(2^n)}^a<\infty,$$ then I would know solve it (with comparison test, because $(2^n)^{a-1}{f(2^n)}^a\leq n^{a-1}{f(n)}^a$ for all $n=0,1,2,...$). But I don't know how to prove $(1)$.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test